# Serializing and Deserializing GraphQLSchema to/from Database

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I would like to serialize a `GraphQLSchema` to a string and then write it to a database and then deserialize it back into a `GraphQLObjectType` after reading it back from the database. Something like:

```
const gqlSchemaString = printSchema(new GraphQLSchema({
    query: graphqlObjectType
  })
)

db.write(key, gqlSchemaString)

const s = db.read(key)

// Convert s back into GraphQLObjectType??
```

The reason why I am doing this is because I'm trying to persist all of the GraphQLObjects that are registered with my service and then create a union type of all of them and register the schema using the union type. For example:

```
const gqlTypes = db.list()

const union = new GraphQLUnionType({
  name: 'CloudEventPayload',
  gqlTypes
})

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
      cloudEventTypes: {
        type: union
      }
    }
  })
})
```

What's the best way to achieve this with the `graphql-js` library?